# Different backgrounds in one Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In Android, is it possible to *properly* have different background color for the views, the empty space and the action bar?

For example I have a PreferenceScreen in a PreferenceFragment. I have these codes:

Style XML:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue1</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/bg</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/brown1</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/brown1</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

my PreferenceFragment class: this already looks like a hack!

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v=super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    ((ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list)).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1));
    return v;
}
```

This already makes the ListView items have `bg` background color, and the empty space after them `blue1` background color *(note that I had to set them in the opposite way to make this work!)*, and the ActionBar has `brown1` background but the text on it does not and that's really ugly! Also, what the heck does `windowBackground` do anyway?

[image]

**EDIT:** I've been able to change the background of the title with this hack:

```
int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
    if (title != null)
        title.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brown1));
}
```

Now how do I do this for the logo and the "Up" arrow to the left of the logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the `titleTextStyle` from the style XML.